# Rails 3: Show Real-Time Data to User from Node.js/MongoDB

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, node.js, real-time

I have a Rails web app that shows data to user, however, that data is not being shown in real-time even though a node.js server is adding the data in real-time to a cloud database that the Rails app has access.

How can I show the data in Rails, from the database, as soon as it arrives?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I show the data in Rails, from
>   the database, as soon as it arrives?

How about doing it the other way: as soon as your data arrives and are stored in DB, you can send them to clients through [socket.io](http://socket.io/) established connection for example.

Comment: do you have some documentation on implementing this with ruby on rails 3.1 and on how to make `socket.io` listen for database changes?

Comment: @Mr_Nizzle Socket.io itself doesn't listen for database changes, but you can for example use pub/sub mechanism where RoR app would be a publisher and node.js app subscriber for changes which were made in database. If you use CouchDB then it might be even simpler because it has changes feed feature built-in.

Comment: Thanks. look i found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551630/rails-3-1-js-socket-io-emit-in-js-erb-gets-not-executed-and-prevents-execu and it seems he found the way on getting it working no i see in my nodeJS debug this: `websocket received data packet 5:::{"name":"message","args":["{&quot;data&quot;:&quot;fooo&quot;}"]}` but in the pages where I'm listening the socket nothing happens `socket.on('message' ...`